# Document being cutoff in table

Tags: html, html-table

In my html document, I am using the table elements to create a sort of photo collage grid. When I change the `z-index` to `-1` for my post it just cuts off the document and you have to scroll to see it, this is very confusing, please help. Thanks

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kg3P/embedded/result/) of it

Comment: Don't abuse tables like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed your ordered list div #posts is the direct child of body? Just remove the style of body like `height: 100%; background: #e1e1e1;` and it'll work. Hope this works for you.